# Not deprecated equivalent to start-dfs

Tags: hadoop

I used `Hadoop 2.2.0`.
For now, when I start a node, I execute the following command :

```
start-dfs
```

However, a warning states it is deprecated :

```
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated
Instead use the hdfs command for it.
```

What is the good command to use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, there are two commands to use :

1. `hdfs namenode`
2. `hdfs datanode`